# RSpec testing with followerships / friendships has many through users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, has-many-through

I inspired myself with the following link, http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association, but the rspec testing is not coming easy.

**user model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_many :followerships
  has_many :followers, :through => :followerships
  has_many :inverse_followerships, :class_name => "Followership", :foreign_key => "follower_id"
  has_many :inverse_followers, :through => :inverse_followerships, :source => :user
end
```

**followership model:**

```
class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
end
```

**followerhip factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :followership do
    user_id 1
    follower_id 1
  end
end
```

**followerships controller:**

```
class FollowershipsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def create
    @followership = current_user.followerships.build(:follower_id => params[:follower_id])
    if @followership.save
      flash[:notice] = "Following."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to follow."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @followership = current_user.followerships.find(params[:id])
    @followership.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed followership."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

**folowerships controller spec (this is all wrong):**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe FollowershipsController do
  let!(:followership) { create(:followership) }
  let!(:follower) { followership.follower }
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    sign_in :user, user
  end

  describe "#create" do
    it "saves the followership" do
      post :create, followership: { follower_id: follower }

      expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
      expect(assigns(:followership).followership.followers).to eq(user)
      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Following.")
    end

    it "fails to save followership" do
      expect(post :create, followership: { follower_id: follower }).to redirect_to(root_path)
      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Unable to follow.")
    end
  end

  describe "#destroy" do
    it "deletes the followership" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: follower
      }.to change(Followership, :count).by(-1)

      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Removed followership.")
    end
  end

end
```

**Error from followerships controller Rspec**

```
FollowershipsController
  #destroy
    deletes the followership (FAILED - 1)
  #create
    saves the followership (FAILED - 2)
    fails to save followership (FAILED - 3)

Failures:

  1) FollowershipsController#destroy deletes the followership
     Failure/Error: delete :destroy, id: follower

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"followerships", :id=>nil}

  2) FollowershipsController#create saves the followership
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:followership).followership.followers).to eq(user)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `followership' for #<Followership:0x00000109f69780>

  3) FollowershipsController#create fails to save followership
     Failure/Error: expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Unable to follow.")

       expected: "Unable to follow."
            got: "Following."

       (compared using ==)
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The `let` command uses lazy evaluation, so these records are not actually created until called. Use the `let!` syntax to ensure they're created before your tests run:

```
  let!(:followership) { create(:followership) }
  let!(:follower) { followership.follower }
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
```

Make sure your validations also only allow creation of a following if it doesn't already exist for that pair of users:

```
class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :follower_id
```

Also, it's not guaranteed that the `follower`/`followership` relationships will belong to `user` since `user` doesn't necessarily have an `id` of 1.

Finally, `assigns` is a method, so the syntax should be `assigns(:followership)` not `assigns[:followership]`

Comment: hi Anthony, I accepted your comments. I know that the factory and the Rspec are not working... any ideas ? thanks